# Restrictions for postfix submission port

Tags: postfix, smtp

I would like to set up Postfix (on ubuntu 14.04) to use the submission port but I'm worried It may become an open relay. I would like to know what are the best restrictions for each of the restrictions lists (which by default have the $mua_ variables, meaning basically no restrictions at all?)

Here is the default master.cf configuration in Ubuntu:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

And here is what `postconf -Mx` (will expand the $mua_ variables) says:

```
submission inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions= 
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

So, here I'm guessing that, as long as the user is a SASL authenticated user he or she will be able to send emails using whichever account and to any destination, no helo or client restrictions (I'm guessing this is because MUAs -like outlook- and not servers will be connection to this port so you don't want to be too picky)

Some restrictions I think would be nice despite that fact would be:

- `reject_non_fqdn_sender` and `reject_unlisted_sender` for `smtpd_sender_restrictions`
- `reject_non_fqdn_recipient` for `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`

What are other desirable restrictions on these restriction lists?

Answer (score 1):

It will never become an open relay if you are **requiring authentication**.

If you are worried your users do not use good passwords you could restrict networks to specific IP ranges, either with postfix, iptables, or external firewalls.

Another good thought would be to add fail2ban as a brute force protection mechanism.

As with any email system, you should always monitor for abuse, be sure to have a valid postmaster mailbox as well as abuse.  Also monitoring RBLs and being set up with feedback loops is good practice.